# Position images side by side

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I am trying to align two images horizontally on my page and then another two underneath them horizontally so that I end up with a grid of four images all contained within a div.

I have the images contained within the div I just cannot align them to how I want them to be.

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi, please supply your current code in a [mcve], so we have a better idea of your current approach. Otherwise, there aren't enough details here to provide a proper solution to your problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gnph0av3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **multiple** ways to achieve this. 
Positioning is one of the main parts of CSS.

1. set container width e.g.: 
   `.container { width: 600px; }`

   set child to a **fraction** of containers size
    `.child { width: 250px; }`
   *note.: if .child is a <div> remember to set .child's `display: inline-block;`*
2. same as above but with **dynamic units**. `%, vh, vw, em, rem`
3. use CSS3 **Flexbox**:

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center; 
}
.child {
  width: 250px;               /* fraction of container's size */
  margin: 2px;
}
```

4. use a Layout Framework's grid, e.g.: **Bootstrap**.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <img>
    <img>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <img>
    <img>
  </div>
</div>
```

here's a **fiddle** with the 4 examples. https://jsfiddle.net/warkentien2/otgns8hx/1/

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

The parent div need to have a width of 100%.
The img need have 50% as width. Give a specific height to your img so that they all have the same. Add box-sizing: border-box; so that your padding will be calculated in the width. Finally add float: left; to place the image.

I don't recommand diplay: flex since not all browser support it.

```
.parent {
  width:100%;
}
.parent img {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L8vx30v0/2/

Comment: setting the width to 50% doesn't account for margins and padding. also it's more advisable to display:inline-block rather than adding a float. height should also be set in %, not pixels

Comment: to account for border and margin just add `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: I forgot to write display: inline-block. Adding box-sizing: border-box; should fix the padding/margin problem. Why do pixel height wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have only 4 images you could go for the simpliest solution with two lists and `display: flex`

https://jsfiddle.net/dgsgy1Ly/1/